# terraform AWS ami datasource filter problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following filter for a datasource to find ami id's for an EC2 instance,

```
data "aws_ami" "i_got_this_from_data_source" {
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["amazon"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm*"]
  }
/*  
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ebs"]
  }

 filter {
    name   = "architecture"
    values = ["x86_64"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "platform"
    values = ["Linux/UNIX"]
  }*/
}
```

I want a search similar to the one below but even from aws cli I can't find any images if I use anything but the uncommented part in the filter.
[image]

Here's the aws cli command I tried. Removing parts didn't help until I removed all but the name again.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region eu-central-1  --owners amazon  --filters "Name=platform,Values=Linux/UNIX" "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" "Name=name,Values=amzn2-ami-hvm*" "Name=name,Values=ebs" "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the filter `"Name=platform,Values=Linux/UNIX"` is not needed since you specified the name of Amazon Linux Image.
Also, `"Name=name,Values=ebs"` must be `"Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs"`
So, the request must be

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region eu-central-1  --owners amazon --filters "Name=name,Values=amzn2-ami-hvm*" "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64"
```

Comment: thanks, this does work but also brings -gp2 images as well. Is there a way to filter further by name to only contain ebs in the name.

Comment: Try to add  `"Name=block-device-mapping.volume-type,Values=standard"` (replace ebs type as you need). See the docs for available filters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html